# Re-Arrange Table (summarize only certain rows)

Tags: sql-server

I have the following Table:
[image]

Thus, whenever I have common “J No”, I would like to perform the following calculations:

Take only the 1st value from “Set up Start” and combine it with the last two values from “Run Start” and “Run End” and delete any records in between them.

Here is my Query code:

```
SELECT 
   [LineNo]
  ,[J No]
  ,[FC]
  ,[SetupStart]
  ,[UpTimeStart]
  ,[UpTimeEnd]
  ,[Setup]
  ,[UpTime]
  ,[Targ Len]
  ,[Act Len]
  ,[R Up F]
  ,[R Dn F]
  ,[Scrap]
FROM [Initial].[dbo].[vWGetProductionInfo]
ORDER BY SetupStart ASC, UpTimeEnd AS
```

How would I do modify this query to give me the desired output I have listed above?

Comment: looks like achievable using just a simple `GROUP BY` with `MIN` and `MAX`

Comment: Except maybe for `Uptime` and `Setup` which is the value attached to a specific row.

Comment: You may need to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign an ordinal to each row then pick out the complete row using that ordinal.

Comment: How do you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this as mentioned by Squirrel

```
SELECT [J No]
    ,MIN([SetupStart]) AS [SetupStart]
    ,MAX(UpTimeStart) AS UpTimeStart
    ,MAX(UpTimeEnd) AS UpTimeEnd
FROM [Initial].[dbo].[vWGetProductionInfo]
GROUP BY [J No]
```